# Replacing a PSU with higher wattage one

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

My PC has a `APEVIA 800WATT GOLD 80 PLUS POWER SUPPLY`.

I did some research and found recommended wattage for my GPU is 900W.

Also per my research any ATX PSU fits in my PC case.

Only remaining question which I could not find answer is if a
`APEVIA 1000WATT GOLD 80 PLUS POWER SUPPLY`  also works with my motherboard.

So If I go with higher wattage PSU can it possibly damage my pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it fits (you have done that). Make sure all the required voltages on all lines are correct. Make sure the current capacity of each line is at least the minimum or more.

Then overall, power is pulled NOT pushed, so the computer will only draw what it needs.

So if all the details are good and meet at least minimum, then assuming the new PSU to be of good quality, it will not likely damage the board or computer.

Comment: Well, I find issue with your last statement - if the PSU is built with components from low quality suppliers weird and funny (though not haha-funny type) things can happen.
Not enough info given on the PSU in OP is what makes your statement dubious. For example, internet-based-general-knowledge-fund recommendation is: if it's Apevia, then better avoid it.
Had OP went with Platinum, then I would have not had an issue with the answer...

Comment: The new PSU should work, but I changed my answer to say "likely" and not be so black and white.

Comment: Yeah, it's the quality of the question that is the problem here, really. Switching for higher wattage PSU is a no-brainer, it's the choice the OP made that makes it an issue...
I would never cut corner on PSU - mine is a Seasonic Focus Plus Platinum - so while I agree with the answer in principle, it's the choice that makes it... not so black and white.

Comment: @AcePL , Answer is very precise. Also question is crystal clear. OP wants to see if he can replace Same Brand PSU APEVIA with a higher wattage of same brand PSU. Simple answer is Computer will only draws the Wattage it needs , so Wattage of PSU is irrelevant. Also with all due respect no one care what kind of PSU you are using as it is not related to the question asked. I don't see anyone asking what type of PSU is better. If that's the case why not go for Titanium?

Comment: @BTFman - You see, the question asks not only if higher wattage will damage PSU (which it will not, obviously), but it also contains indicated specific type of PSU (more or less)... And WE KNOW that poor quality PSU can damage PC (not just in case of failure). And as for the answer - yes, it is very precise NOW.
As for your question - i went with mine because of low noise level, with platinum because power savings between Gold and Platinum already paid for my PSU, which I got for excellent price (Titanium price was out of my range). In other words: what a stupid question...